# evaluate src blocks only if individually pressed and not if globally executed

Tags: org-mode, babel

Is there a way to enable source block execution only if C-c C-c is pressed and keep them silent when C-c C-v C-b is used, i.e. all source blocks are executed?

Comment: I don't undestand what you are asking: `C-c C-c` will execute the code block at point, `C-c C-v C-b` will execute all code blocks in the buffer. So what exactly do you want done differently? What does "keep them silent" mean?

Comment: I want a flag which keeps certain blocks from being executed if hit C-c C-v C-b but keep getting executed if invoked by C-c C-c

Comment: OK - thanks for the clarification. There is no such flag however: `C-c C-v C-b` is bound to `org-babel-execute-buffer`: this just loops over all the source blocks and calls `org-babel-execute-src-block` which is what `C-c C-c` is (effectively) bound to. So any flag that would inhibit one, would also inhibit the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can "deactivate" a block with the `:eval no` header argument. You could also try to cache the results, using the `:cache yes`, which would not re-execute the block unless its contents has changed.

References:

- https://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-Code-Blocks.html#Evaluating-Code-Blocks
- https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-Header-Arguments.html#Using-Header-Arguments